# ListView with switch buttons, setChecked on start two switches, and save state of another

Tags: android, android-listview, switch-statement

I have two problems:

What am I trying to achieve is a listview with switch button in each row and it's working fine, but I want to set on start 4th and 5th switch on True

holder.s.setChecked(possition==4);

holder.s.setChecked(possition==5);

setting on true only the 5th, how to do this, give me any hint?

Second problem: While scrolling my listview changing state of switch buttons, I've tried many many tutorials but with no luck, how to keep state of switch buttons?

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    String pytanie = getItem(position);


    if (convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardio_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        holder.s = (Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Model_cardio question = getItem(position);
    holder.question.setText(pytanie);
    holder.s.setChecked(position == 4);
    holder.s.setChecked(position == 5);
    holder.s.setTag(position);


    return convertView;
}
```

---

EDIT:
I've added this, and want to store a state in some list

```
  holder.s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the two statements

```
holder.s.setChecked(position == 4);
holder.s.setChecked(position == 5);
```

are executed one after the other. For **each** position.

So for position number 4, the first statement results in the `Switch` being checked, only to be unchecked again in the following statement.

You could introduce a `boolean` variable:

```
boolean doCheck = (position == 4) || (position == 5);
holder.s.setChecked(doCheck);
```

The trickier part of the question is how to keep track of checked list rows.
For this, you need a kind of `List` like

```
ArrayList<Integer> checkedRows;
```

In the constructor of the adapter, you can initialize the list as needed.

```
checkedList = new ArrayList();
// if you like, you can add rows 4 and 5 as checked now
// and drop the respective code in 'getView()':
checkedList.add(4);
checkedList.add(5);
```

Then in the `getView()` method, you examine each `View`:

```
holder.s.setTag(position);
holder.s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

if (checkedList.contains(position) )
{
    holder.s.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
    holder.s.setChecked(false);
}

holder.s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked )
            {
                checkedList.add((Integer)buttonView.getTag() );
            }
            else
            {
                checkedList.remove((Integer)buttonView.getTag() );
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Thank You! Do You have any idea how to save state of checked switches, so when user is scrolling a list switches not losing their state?

Comment: In this case you have to keep track of checked list items and in the getView() method of the adapter you have to explicitly set the checked / unchecked state for each list item

Comment: @klijakub - for "how to keep track...", I'd like to point you to an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585249) I posted some weeks ago. Please tell me if you need further information

Comment: @0x0nsugar you're using baseadapter, in my case I'm using ArrayAdapter<String> Thank you for your help, look at my edit, is it possible to do it in a very simple way, for example user change state of 6th element, onCheckedChanged() adding it to list, and then holder.s.setChecked(ListWithAllStates); ?

Comment: @Klijakub - I had used ArrayAdapter in that answer until Selvin told me not to :) - I'll edit my answer and include the track-keeping part

Comment: @0x0nsugar  
Thank you for your tremendous help!:)

Comment: @klijakub - ok. Now I hope the "remove" will not get interpreted as "remove(index)" but as "remove(Object)"

Comment: @0x0nsugar checkedList.add((Integer)buttonView.getTag() ); checkedList.remove((Integer)buttonView.getTag() ); messing all, without those it's setting fine 4th and 5th, but when I add those it is checking random swtiches after scroll, don't understand this at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96281/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-klijakub).