# Remedies to Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android

The following code generates `NullPointerException` in Android.

```
searchResults.setText(searchResultString);
```

Where:

- searchResults is a TextView
- searchResultString is a String

Can somebody list out the possible reasons why this may be happening?

Comment: It seems you are trying to set a String type to a TextView type. Maybe this person's post will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12201919/3173748.

Also, this is a very poorly worded question. Please give the context of your problem when asking the question to get better help (i.e. "I am trying to setText to a TextView but I get this error" )

Answer (score 0):

So your textView not binding or attaching correctly. Other wise **setText** expecting string and your codes should work.
Check where you bind your searchResult object.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the searchResults TextView is initialized in Android. This is a very common programming mistake in Android.

You can initialize it like this.

```
TextView searchResults;
searchResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchResultsTextView);
```

Let me know if this solution works out.

Just make sure that the binding between the java file and the xml file is done properly for the given text view.